# Whats the right design pattern for the following code?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have following classes:

```
class ServiceA{
    User getUser(){} // API call to userServiceA.com
    Profile getProfile(){} // API call to profileServiceA.com
}

class ServiceB{
    User getUser(){} // API call to userServiceB.com
    Profile getProfile(){} // API call to profileServiceB.com
}

class GroupService(){
    ServiceA serviceA;
    ServiceB serviceB;
    constructor(){
        this.serviceA = new ServiceA();
        this.serviceB = new ServiceB();
    }

    getUser(String type){
        if(type.equals("A")){
            serviceA.getUser();
        }else if(type.equals("B")){
            serviceB.getUser();
        }
    }
}

class Controller(){
    get(RC routingContext){
        String type = routingContext.getParam("type");
        GroupService groupService = new GroupService();
        groupService.getUser(type);
    }
}
```

In this project `ServiceC,D,E...` will be kept adding, and that will turn the `GroupService` class into a chaos.

For this particular scenario, which is the correct design pattern I can apply? `Factory` pattern is one solution, but then `if else` or `Map` will still exist.

**Update: Using Strategy Pattern**

```
public interface ServiceAZ {
  User getUser();
  Profile getProfile();
}

class ServiceA implements ServiceAZ{

  @Override
  public User getUser() {
            return // API call to userServiceA.com
  }

  @Override
  public Profile getProfile() {
      return // API call to profileServiceA.com
  }
}

class ServiceB implements ServiceAZ{

  @Override
  public User getUser() {
            return // API call to userServiceB.com
  }

  @Override
  public Profile getProfile() {
      return // API call to profileServiceB.com
  }
}

class GroupService(){
    private ServiceAZ service;
    GroupService(ServiceAZ s){
        this.service = s;
    }
    User getUser(){
        service.getUser();
    }
}

class Controller(){
    get(routingContext){
        String type = routingContext.getParam("type");
        ServiceAZ service; 
        if(type.equals("A")){
            service = new ServiceA();
        }
        if(type.equals("B")){
            service = new ServiceB();
        }
        GroupService groupService = new GroupService(service);
        groupService.getUser(type);
    }
}
```

This looks much better but now in the controller, the `if else` is a problem

Comment: Well, if you move         this.serviceA = new ServiceA();
        this.serviceB = new ServiceB(); to getUser(), then it becomes a proper factory. But looking at the code, it seems a behavioral pattern would suit more. Strategy, may be?

Comment: I applied `Strategy` pattern,  but the only problem is the `if else`. Have updated the answer.

Comment: thats great. Although it'll be good to know, that strategy pattern creates a structure for your strategies, it doesn't tell you which strategy to pick. that decision making you'll have to manually, i'm afraid.